# Get the ElementType enum defined in a custom annotation thought @Target annotation

Tags: java, reflection

Let’s say I have this annotation:

```
@Target(METHOD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface LifeTime {
    long minutes();
    long seconds();
}
```

Is there a way to retrieve the `ElementType` enum defined using the `Annotation` class?

```
Annotation[] annotations = method.getDeclaredAnnotations();

for (Annotation annotation: annotations) {
    if (annotation.WHAT? == ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE) {

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `LifeTime` type that is annotated with `@Target`, not some `method`.

Retrieve the annotation from the `Class` object representing `Target`, and use its [`value`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Target.html#value--) method.

```
Target target = LifeTime.class.getAnnotation(Target.class);
ElementType[] elementTypes = target.value();
```

Comment: Thanks, I get it. But still, I'm getting the annotations from the method, so I would expect to be able to retrieve the associated target for each one of them.

Comment: @VíctorAlbertos No, `LifeTime` is the annotation on the method, not `Target`. Also, if you know that you're scanning methods for annotations, why would you need the `@Target` saying that you can annotate a method?

Comment: Because I need to validate that an specific method (retrieve dynamically using Proxy class from a non implemented interface) has been decorate with only one annotation which Target is Method.

Comment: @VíctorAlbertos That doesn't make sense. If you're scanning for annotations on a method, then the corresponding annotation MUST be annotated with `@Target` with a `value` of either the empty array or an array that contains `METHOD`. There's no point looking for that, you already know.

Comment: @VíctorAlbertos Again, there's no need to check for `@Target`. If `method.getDeclaredAnnotations()` returns an array with more than 1 element, then it is invalid, by your rules.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought that method.getDeclaredAnnotations() returned also the annotations with Target PARAMETER. Sorry about that.

Comment: @victor There is another method that provides the annotations for each parameter, if you need those.